# Spring onchange submit, form object is null

Tags: java, javascript, spring, internet-explorer-9

I have a form in a portlet page with two drop-down menus; I'd like to submit the form every time the user selects a value from the first menu, so that I can populate the second one. The real submit is handled when the user clicks on a button which calls a JavaScript that sets a discriminating parameter before submitting the form.

This is the action bean from the page which successfully redirects to the JSP *inserisciOrganoEnteBando*:

```
<bean id="aggiungiEnteOrganoBando" class="it.milano.comune.pi.nomine.service.AggiungiEnteOrganoBando">
        <property name="sessionForm" value="true" />
        <property name="commandName" value="aggiungiEnteOrganoBandoForm" />
        <property name="commandClass" value="it.milano.comune.pi.nomine.backoffice.model.AggiungiEnteOrganoBandoForm" />
        <property name="formView" value="gestisciOrganiEntiBando" />
        <property name="successView" value="inserisciOrganoEnteBando" />
        <property name="entiOrganiDao" ref="entiOrganiDao" />
        <property name="entiDao" ref="entiDao" />
</bean>
```

with this `onSubmitRender` method in the `AggiungiEnteOrganoBando` controller:

```
protected ModelAndView onSubmitRender(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, Object obj, BindException exceptions)
    throws Exception {
        PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession();
        Map results = (Map) session.getAttribute("results");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(getSuccessView(), "results", results);
        Map listaEnti= (Map)results.get("listaEnti");
        mav.addObject("listaEnti", listaEnti);
        return mav;
}
```

This is the form from the JSP *inserisciOrganoEnteBando*:

```
<form id="insertEnteOrganoBandoForm" name="insertEnteOrganoBandoForm" method="POST" class="form-search"
    action='<portlet:actionURL>
    <portlet:param name="action" value="insertEnteOrganoBando" />
    </portlet:actionURL>'
    >
    <label for="id_ente">Ente</label>
            <select id="id_ente" name="id_ente" onchange="realSubmit('KO')">
                <option value="" label="Seleziona ente"/>
                <c:forEach var="lie" items="${listaEnti}">
                    <option value="<c:out value="${lie.key}"/>" label="<c:out value="${lie.value}"/>" />
                </c:forEach>
            </select><br>
    <label for="id_ente_organo">Organo</label>
            <select id="id_ente_organo" name="id_ente_organo">
                <option value="" label="Seleziona organo"/>
                <c:forEach var="leo" items="${listaEntiOrgani}">
                    <option value="<c:out value="${leo.key}"/>" label="<c:out value="${leo.value}"/>" />
                </c:forEach>
            </select><br>
    <label for="descrizione">Descrizione</label>
        <textarea id="descrizione" name="descrizione"></textarea><br>
    <input type="hidden" id="tipoSubmit" name="tipoSubmit"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_bando" name="id_bando" value="<%= id_bando %>"/>
    <input type="button" id="confirmInsertEnteOrganoBando" name="confirmInsertEnteOrganoBando" class="wpsButtonText btn" value="Aggiungi"
    onclick="realSubmit('OK')"/>
</form>
```

The variables *id_bando*, *listaEnti* and *listaEntiOrgani* are all correctly passed to the JSP from the previous controller and the first drop-down is correctly populated while the second one is empty as expected.

This is the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var realSubmit = function(stato){
    $("#tipoSubmit").val(stato);
    document.forms["insertEnteOrganoBandoForm"].submit();
};
</script>
```

I use the variable `tipoSubmit` to check whether the user is really submitting the form or has simply chosen an element from the first drop-down menu.

This is the form object:

```
public class InsertEnteOrganoBandoForm {

    private Long id_ente;
    private Long id_ente_organo;
    private String descrizione;
    private String tipoSubmit;
    private Long id_bando;

    public Long getId_ente() {
        return id_ente;
    }
    public void setId_ente(Long id_ente) {
        this.id_ente = id_ente;
    }
    public Long getId_ente_organo() {
        return id_ente_organo;
    }
    public void setId_ente_organo(Long id_ente_organo) {
        this.id_ente_organo = id_ente_organo;
    }
    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }
    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }
    public String getTipoSubmit() {
        return tipoSubmit;
    }
    public void setTipoSubmit(String tipoSubmit) {
        this.tipoSubmit = tipoSubmit;
    }
    public Long getId_bando() {
        return id_bando;
    }
    public void setId_bando(Long id_bando) {
        this.id_bando = id_bando;
    }
}
```

This is the action bean:

```
<bean id="insertEnteOrganoBando" class="it.milano.comune.pi.nomine.service.InsertEnteOrganoBando">
        <property name="sessionForm" value="true" />
        <property name="commandName" value="insertEnteOrganoBandoForm" />
        <property name="commandClass" value="it.milano.comune.pi.nomine.backoffice.model.InsertEnteOrganoBandoForm" />
        <property name="formView" value="inserisciOrganoEnteBando" />
        <property name="successView" value="inserisciOrganoEnteBando" />
        <property name="bandiEntiOrganiDao" ref="bandiEntiOrganiDao" />
        <property name="entiOrganiDao" ref="entiOrganiDao" />
        <!-- <property name="validator" ref="insertEnteOrganoBandoValidator" />-->
</bean>
```

The validator is temporarily disabled, the DAOs are correctly initialized and injected and the bean is mapped with:

```
<entry key="insertEnteOrganoBando" value-ref="insertEnteOrganoBando" />
```

My issue is that when the `formBackingObject` method is called from the `InsertEnteOrganoBando` controller, the `sessionForm` object is `null`, not even an empty form.

```
protected Object formBackingObject(PortletRequest request) throws Exception {
    PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession();
    InsertEnteOrganoBandoForm sessionForm = (InsertEnteOrganoBandoForm) session.getAttribute("InsertEnteOrganoBandoForm");
    if (sessionForm != null)return sessionForm;
    return super.formBackingObject(request);
}
```

This structure is exactly the same I used for every other page/controller/form/... in my portlet without issues. I checked all the names for misspellings or different cases and everything is fine.

What am I missing?

PS: I know about AJAX, but I **CANNOT** use it, I'm working with Java 4, Spring 2, IBM WebSphere 6, Eclipse, IE9 and I cannot go in Java debug mode, only JavaScript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. As often times is, it was a simple mistake from my part.

The drop-down fields `id_ente` and `id_ente_organo` are Long in my form object but in my JSP I was putting in a default option with value `""`, `<option value="" label="Seleziona organo"/>`.

This didn't play well with Spring which upon form submission wasn't setting that field to `null` as I expected and failed silently.

Setting a default value of -1 did the job for me: `<option value="-1" label="Seleziona organo"/>`